# iTextSharp not including template using PdfSmartCopy

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I have a PDF with a hidden template that is added based on a button click using javascript. This works fine in the original PDF. When the PDF is used to create a new PDF with PdfSmartCopy, the template is not included. All other form fields work fine, the hidden template is the only item not copied. Is there something I need to do to include templates?

```
Dim newFile As String = "C:\New.pdf"
Dim streamOut As New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create)
Dim newDoc As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4)
Dim pdfCopy As PdfSmartCopy = New PdfSmartCopy(newDoc, streamOut)
pdfCopy.SetMergeFields()
newDoc.Open()
Dim pdfTemplate As String = "C:\PDFwithTemplate.pdf"
Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
pdfCopy.AddDocument(PdfReader)
pdfCopy.Close()
pdfReader.Close()
```

Comment: `PdfCopy` and related classes only copy pages and page related information. Page templates, on the other hand, are not pages. Furthermore, there is hardly any high level page template support in itext.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this, such as inserting a page that includes a template using PdfStamper?

Comment: As far as I know the only option is to stamp the PDF with the page template and add all the other pages to it. (Alternatively one can consider instantiating the page template to start with, use PDF copy, and in the merged result make the page instance a template again. But you also might have to re-add JavaScript again: global JavaScript also is not copied by `PdfCopy` and friends.)

Comment: @mkl Thank you for the information on all counts. I was able to work it out by creating one PDF with all pages, then using pdfReader.SelectPages to choose only the pages needed for different versions. All templates and javascript are retained.

Comment: Yes, stamping (after `pdfReader.SelectPages` you use a `PdfStamper`, I presume) keeps document level stuff.